# How to stop Go 1.11 from building quicktemplate .qtpl files?

Tags: go

I have some Go packages that use [quicktemplate](https://github.com/valyala/quicktemplate). Quicktemplate compiles template files with the `.qtpl` extension to Go files with the `.qtpl.go` extension using the `qtc` CLI app. In Go versions prior to 1.11, having `.qtpl` files in a Go package wasn't a problem as the `.qtpl` files would be ignored by the compiler. However, Go 1.11 appears to process `.qtpl` files, causing compilation failures.

An example that works with Go 1.3-1.10 but not 1.11 is available here and described below.

- Source: https://github.com/grokify/gocharts/tree/master/charts/c3
- Build Logs: https://travis-ci.org/grokify/gocharts/builds/431794367 (Go 1.0-1.11)

The package directory contains:

- `timeseries_page.qtpl` template file
- `timeseries_page.qtpl.go` template file compiled to Go using `qtc`

Previously, only the file ending in `.go` would be compiled and everything builds fine. With 1.11, there is an error thrown while parsing the `.qtpl` file which isn't intended to be built by the Go compiler.

Here is a minimal Go program using that package will fail to build in Go 1.11, but work with 1.10.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/grokify/gocharts/charts/c3"
)

func main() {
    _ = c3.C3Chart{}
}
```

Here's the error showing the `timeseries_page.qtpl` file:

```
$ go build main.go
# github.com/grokify/gocharts/charts/c3
timeseries_page.qtpl:42: undefined: TimeseriesHTML
timeseries_page.qtpl:48: undefined: TimeseriesHTML
```

`TimeseriesHTML` is a function that is called in that template file and built by another quicktemplate file in the [`timeseries_js.qtpl.go` file](https://github.com/grokify/gocharts/blob/master/charts/c3/timeseries_js.qtpl.go#L120-L132).

The same result and output is encountered with the following:

```
$ go run main.go
$ go test main.go
```

Is there a way to get back the prior Go behavior, or ignore `.qtpl` files during builds?

Comment: What command are you using that results in this error?

Comment: This is encountered with `go build`, `go run`, and `go test`. I've added more description above.

Comment: I wonder if this this is a problem compiling the .qtpl.go file, and that it's only reporting the line number in the .qtpl file because of the directives like `//line timeseries_page.qtpl:41` in `timeseries_page.qtpl.go`. That isn't a complete answer of course but might help you find the problem.